# Backbone: Getting JSON file from server, to use extension ".json" or not to use it, with url or urlRoot

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am doing some exercise to familiarise myself with Backbone. I'm trying to get a JSON file from my server using `urlRoot` property of the `Model`.

I get error (404) that says it cannot find the file when I type `urlRoot: "./js/json/todo"` but if I type it this way `urlRoot: "./js/json/todo.json"` then it finds it but `console.log(todoItem.get('description'))` says `undefined`.

Now, in many Backbone applications that I've seen, most of the time the extension `.json` is not applied, i.e. this suffices `urlRool: "/todos"` instead of `urlRoot: "/todos.json"`. But when I do it without the extension, I get errors.

- Can someone explain to me how to use `url` and `urlRoot` properties properly?
- And also, what is the issue with not using `.json` or using it?
- And lastly, is my JSON file format below, good for Backbone?

Backbone:

```
(function(window, $, Backbone) {
    var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({ urlRoot: './js/json/todos' });

    var todoItem = new TodoItem({id: 1});

    todoItem.fetch();

    console.log(todoItem.get('description')); // This is undefined in the console

}(window, jQuery, Backbone));
```

JSON:

```
{
    "todos": [
    {
        "description": "Pick Up Milk",
        "status": "incomplete"
    },

    {
        "description": "Do shopping at Market",
        "status": "incomplete"
    }]
}
```

Comment: The examples you see are probably not using static files but rather a web service that returns json as the result.  Without the examples you have seen, it is just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see it without `.json` because the backend someone is using is returning JSON from the url without `.json`. When I have a static JSON file, I just add `.json` to it.

It's all about the server setup or whatever you have handling urls.

And as far as your format, you don't need the wrapping `{}`. It can be just:

```
[{
    "description": "Pick Up Milk",
    "status": "incomplete"
},

{
    "description": "Do shopping at Market",
    "status": "incomplete"
}]
```

So, my GET is a little more manual when using a static JSON file:

```
$.ajax("./js/json/todo.json").done(function(data) {
    // I'm only using extend to add in the id. You could just use data[0]
    var todoItem = new ToDoItem(_.extend(data[0], { id: 1 }));
}
```

Fetch isn't really going to work since your JSON file is a collection. You could create:

```
var ToDoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ToDoItem,
    url: "./js/json/todo.json"
});
var toDos = new ToDoCollection();
toDos.fetch();
```

And that should give you a collection with a model for each entry in the JSON file.

Comment: Hi @kalley, I still this error: `NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/js-web-app/js/json/todos.json/1` when I use `var todoItem = new TodoItem({id: 1});` but if I remove the id property from it firebug says `OK` but then this `console.log(todoItem.get('description'));` is `undefined` even though I have amended my json file as per your example. Why is that? How do I get anything from a json file, i.e. the 1st `"description"` property in the json file above?

Comment: That is because when you try to get a specific model, it assumes you have a structure similar to what @Isaac Suttell mentions. I'm going to update my answer with how I do GETs with a static JSON

Comment: Thanks for this @kalley. So does that mean that `urlRoot` is only good for a single object and not a list of objects? So how do I use `urlRoot`?

Comment: It is if you have a way to pull a single record. It will always do a call to `urlRoot + '/' + idAttribute`. If you don't have a server setup to pull based on an id, you can use [url](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url) to give it a specific url. I would venture to say that most people use a collection to generate their models from an array.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether you are using `.json` or not as long as the endpoint exists. So, if you named your file `todo.json` you have to have `.json`. One way to test this is, you should be able to cut and paste the url of the file into your browser and have it display correctly.

I believe you're getting `undefined` because of the format of your JSON file. `description` doesn't exist at the top level of the object. Backbone expects an array of `Models` and not an object containing an array of `Models`. For example:

```
[{
    "description": "Pick Up Milk",
    "status": "incomplete"
},
{
    "description": "Do shopping at Market",
    "status": "incomplete"
}]
```

`url` applies to a collection, `urlRoot` applies to a individual model. What this allows you to do is create a semantic naming schema. For example, to access an API I might use the following schema:

```
GET /todos - Get all todos
GET /todo/:id - Get one todo
```

I can do this by setting the `url` to `/todos` and the `urlRoot` to `/todo`. Backbone will automatically append the ID. Keep in mind `urlRoot` is optional as long as `url` is defined.

Comment: Hi @Isaac Suttell, I still get this error in Firebug: `NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/js-web-app/js/json/todos.json/1`, even when after amending my json as per your example, how come? But if I remove the id property from `var todoItem = new TodoItem({id: 1});` and try to do `console.log(todoItem.get('description'));` I get undefined. I don't know what's happening?

Comment: Backbone automatically appends the Model's `ID` when performing requests on it. That's why it's adding the `/1`. In your test example, you're creating a brand new `TodoItem` and only defining `id`. That's why when you try to get `description` it's undefined. This is a case where you'd probably want to define a default in the Model for `description`. Keep in mind Backbone was really designed to work with an Restful API. You might struggle less if you just make a simple one instead of trying to use a static file. There are many frameworks out there that make this easy.